# Http listener send columns from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, httpserver, httplistener

I'm new on server's technique. I'm connecting a mobile phone with an application server, and aplication server is communicate locally with an sql server.

Is there any method to send and read columns from sql server?
I mean till now i'm sending all columns in a string separated with comma.

When client will take that string it separate them and filling a list or listview...

Example my string has this form:
John,24,1st class

and my client contain this class

```
public class objects()
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Age{get;set;}
   public string SchoolClass{get;set;}

}
```

So when i'm getting response i'm filling each value from my string on each list object.

Is there any other method more effective and faster than this?

```
 var web = new HttpListener();

        web.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");

        Console.WriteLine("Listening..");

        web.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(web.GetContext());

        var context = web.GetContext();

        var response = context.Response;

        string responseString = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        {
          connection.Open();
          using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name,age,SchoolClass from Students",connection))
           using(SqlDataReader read=cmd.ExecuteReader))
         {
           while(read.Read())
           {
              responseString +=read["Name"].ToString() + ",";
              responseString +=read["Age"].ToString() + ",";
              responseString +=read["SchoolClass"].ToString() + ",";
           }

        }

        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

        var output = response.OutputStream;

        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        output.Close();

        web.Stop();

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is your ORM??

Comment: What you mean orm?

Comment: Now I create an example for you and explane that.

Comment: your wellcome! Check answer.